# Fetch rows from Pandas dataframe using conditions in Python3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with following columns.

```
CUI         id          term id term_name 
C0000729    10000057    MDR LLT Abdominal cramps
C0000729    10000056    MDR LLT Abdominal cramp
C0000729    10011286    MDR LLT Cramp abdominal
C0000729    10000058    MDR LLT Abdominal crampy pains
C0000729    10093764    ICD10   PT  Abdominal crampy pains
C0000800    10093765    ICD10   PT  Abdominal pain
C0000800    10000058    MDR LLT Abdominal crampy pains
C0000800    10093764    ICD10AM PT  Abdominal crampy pains
C0000730    10000052    MDR LLT Abdominal cramps back
```

I would like to fetch those rows (per CUI), if term is 'MDR' and and ICDs (ICD10, ICD10AM). But if it is only MDR, exclude it (eg. the last row 'C0000730').

The expected output is:

```
CUI         id          term id term_name 
C0000729    10000057    MDR LLT Abdominal cramps
C0000729    10000056    MDR LLT Abdominal cramp
C0000729    10011286    MDR LLT Cramp abdominal
C0000729    10000058    MDR LLT Abdominal crampy pains
C0000729    10093764    ICD10   PT  Abdominal crampy pains
C0000800    10093765    ICD10   PT  Abdominal pain
C0000800    10000058    MDR LLT Abdominal crampy pains
C0000800    10093764    ICD10AM PT  Abdominal crampy pains
```

I am using following lines of code using the above dataframe.

```
#select only those mappings where ICD and MeDRA both exists for a particular CUI id
s = set(['ICD10','ICD10CM','ICD10AM','MDR'])

dff_mapped = df_umls[df_umls.groupby('CUI')['SAB'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == s)]

dff_mapped = dff_mapped.sort_values(['CUI', 'SAB'],ascending = [True, True])

dff_mapped.to_csv('df_mapped', index = False, sep = ',')
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Unclear what is `MedDRA`

Comment: You mean that you want to remove CUI codes which does not have ICD* 'term id'?

Comment: MedDRA corrected in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right:

```
nonMDR = df[df['term id'].str.startswith('ICD')] # creates a new df with ICDs
term_ids = nonMDR['CUI'].unique() # create an array of unique CUIs
df[df['CUI'].isin(term_ids)] # filter CUIs
```